# 標準入力の中に、変数で与えられる ascii 文字が何個あるかを計算したい

Tags: sh, unix

シェルスクリプトで、標準入力から、変数sepで指定される ASCII 文字が何文字あるか計算したくなりました。これは、どうやったら実現できますか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`od | sort | uniq -c` でヒストグラムを作って検索するスクリプト:

```
#!/bin/sh
sep="$1"
pat="($(set -- $(printf %s "$sep" | od -v -An -tx1) && IFS=\| && echo "$*"))\$"
od -v -An -tx1 | xargs -n1 | sort | uniq -c | grep -E "$pat"
```

実行例:

```
$ echo -e " AB...CD\n abcd " | ./script.sh "aB.C 
"
      2 0a
      3 20
      3 2e
      1 42
      1 43
      1 61
```

`od -w1` を使ってよければ、次のようにして出力をもうすこしわかりやすくできます (微妙ですが)。

```
od -v -An -tax1 -w1 | xargs -n2 | sort -k2 | uniq -c | grep -E "$pat"
```

実行例:

```
$ echo -e " AB...CD\n abcd " | ./a.sh "aB.C 
"
      2 nl 0a
      3 sp 20
      3 . 2e
      1 B 42
      1 C 43
      1 a 61
```

Comment: 文字コードにして処理するというのは、他の回答にも応用出来そうですね。

Answer (score 5):

#### バイト単位で比較すればよい場合

`sep`が一文字で、改行ではない場合

```
#!/bin/sh
sep='X'
fold -bw1 |grep -cFe "$sep"
```

`fold` で入力を1byte毎に改行し、`grep`の`-c`で数えます。
`sep`が正規表現で意味がある文字だと困るので、`-F`も必要。

---

`sep`が複数文字であり得る場合

```
#!/bin/sh
sep='XYZ'
sep_list="$(printf '%s' "$sep" |fold -bw1)"
fold -bw1 |grep -cFe "$sep_list"
```

`grep`に`-F`を指定した場合、パターンは改行で区切って複数渡せます。（他に複数の`-e`で渡す方法も）
`sep`を改行区切りのリストにするのにも、`fold`を使用しました。
`sep`が `-` で始まっていてもオプションとして扱わせないために、`echo`ではなく`printf`を使い、`grep`には`-e`も必要になります。

---

`sep`が改行を含み得る場合

```
#!/bin/sh
sep='XYZ
'
sep_list="$(printf '%s' "$sep" |tr '\n' '\200' |fold -bw1)"
tr '\n\200' '\200\201' |fold -bw1 |LC_CTYPE=C grep -cFe "$sep_list"
```

`grep` は改行を数える事が出来ないので、改行は`tr`で別の文字に変換する事にしました。
改行は非ASCII文字である`\200`(8進数で指定、適当に選びました）に変換します。
入力に元からある`\200`は、さらに別の非ASCII`\201`にしてカウント対象外にします。

しかし、UTF-8 の環境で UTF-8 として不正な文字を`grep`に指定するのはまずいようで、かなり遅くなります。
Tatz Sekine さんのコメントを反映し、ロケールの環境変数を`LC_CTYPE=C` とする事で解決しました。（とりあえず `grep` にだけ指定しています）

#### 文字単位で比較する必要がある場合

例えば Shift-JIS ではマルチバイト文字が ASCII の文字を含んでいます。（「表」が「\」を含んでいるのが有名です）
こういった場合、UTF-8 などに変換して処理する方法があります。
あるいは、適切なロケールが設定された環境で（`fold`のようなバイト単位で分けるような物でなく）マルチバイト文字を一文字として認識できる`GNU sed`のようなツールを使う必要があります。

```
#!/bin/sh
# GNU sed で動作
sep='XYZ
'
sep_list="$(printf '%s' "$sep" |sed 's/./&\n/g' |sed 's/^$/LF/')"
sed 's/./&\n/g' |sed 's/^$/LF/' |grep -xcFe "$sep_list"
```

上記はついでに、`sep` に ASCII 外の文字も指定可能になるというメリットもありますが、遅いです。

---

言語によってはユニコードでも合字を使っており、これは`GNU sed`も一文字と認識してくれないようなので、これを考慮するとユニコードの正規化（例: `uconv -x any-nfc`）を行なう必要もあります。

Comment: 改行を別の非ASCII文字へ置換して遅いのは、`LC_ALL=C` (もしくは `LC_COLLATE=C`) で回避できませんか?

Comment: sep が `-` で始まると grep に対するオプションとして解釈されてしまうので、grep を使っているところは全部 -e を付けたほうがいいと思います。

Comment: @TatzSekine `LC_ALL=C` や `LC_CTYPE=C`で早くなりました。UTF-8 の環境で UTF-8 として不正な文字を指定したのがよくなかったようです。

Comment: @TatzSekine `grep`の件もありがとうございます。とりあえず回答に反映させていただきました。

Comment: 多分、unicode ベースの locale (UTF-8) なら、`\ufffc` http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm が「正しい」置換文字です。

Answer (score 1):

awk を使う場合です。

```
$ wget -O J02050.fasta 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/J02050&display=fasta&download=fasta&filename=J02050.fasta'

$ sep='ATG'
$ cat J02050.fasta |
  sep="$sep" awk -vRS='^$' '
    BEGIN{
      sep=ENVIRON["sep"]
      gsub(/[][^\\-]/, "\\\\&", sep)
      getline f
      print gsub("[" sep "]", "", f)
    }
  '
175
```

※ awk の `-v` オプションで `sep` シェル変数を渡す場合、`\n` などがエスケープシーケンスとして解釈されてしまうが、環境変数経由で渡すとそのまま(`\`(バックスラッシュ) + `n`)となる

```
$ sep='\n'
$ echo '\nabcn\' | sep="$sep" awk ...
=> 4

$ sep=$'\n' # newline
$ echo '\nabcn\' | sep="$sep" awk ...
=> 1
```

**番外編(GNU grep + GNU sed + GNU coreutils)**

GNU grep の `-z` オプション(ファイル全体を一論理行として処理)、GNU sed の `-z` オプション( `NUL(\0)` を論理行の separator として処理)を利用。

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.25
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

$ sep='\n'
$ echo '\nabcn\' | 
  grep -Pzo "$(printf '[%s]' "$(printf '%s' "$sep" |
               sed -z 's/[][^\\-]/\\&/g;s/\n/\\n/')")" |
  tr -d '\0' | wc -c
=> 4

$ sep=$'\n' # newline
$ echo '\nabcn\' ...
=> 1

$ sep=$'\n' # newline
$ echo -n '\nabcn\' ...
=> 0
```

以下は yaegashi さんのヒストグラムスクリプトのマネ。

```
$ sep=$'ATGC\n'
$ tail -n +2 J02050.fasta |
  grep -Pzo "$(printf '[%s]' "$(printf '%s' "$sep" |
               sed -z 's/[][^\\-]/\\&/g;s/\n/\\n/')")" |
  sort -z | uniq -zc | sed -z 's/\n/LF/;s/  $/ SP/' | tr '\0' '\n' | cat -t

    5 LF
   53 A
   73 C
   73 G
   47 T
```

Comment: 手元の `gawk` と `mawk` で試してみたところ、`-vVAR=VALUE` で変数を初期化する場合 \ がスペシャルキャラクターとして解釈されてしまうっぽいので、sep='\n' とかすると誤動作します。

Answer (score 0):

`$sep` に改行を含まない前提でよいならこんな感じ? (適当)

```
#!/bin/sh
sep="$1"
sed "s/[^`echo "$sep" |sed 's/\\(.\\)/\\\\\\1/g'`]*//g" |tr -d '\n' |wc -c
```

Comment: これは GNU sed だと `sep` に a, n, t などが入ってると正しく動作しないと思います。POSIX 的には、BRE ではそもそも `[]` の中では \ でエスケープできない (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) ので、  適当になんでも \ でエスケープという方針は無理があるかと存じます。

Comment: なるほど確かに。適当すぎました。